# How to create find/replace add in with two multiline textboxes

Tags: arrays, vba, replace, textbox

I'm trying to create a find and replace macro for use as an add-in. I'd like to do so with a userform containing two multiline textboxes where users can enter the strings they would like to find and replace.  I've figured out how to put these strings into arrays, but cannot figure out how to match the 'find' array with the 'replace' array and run a Replace command.

Is there some way to give each entry in each array a value, and match them up? I.e. the first string in the 'find' textbox gets a value of 1, the second gets a value of 2, and the same for the 'replace' textbox.  Then the macro replaces any instances of 'find' string value 1 with 'replace' string value 1, and so on.

Here's the code I've figured out so far, thanks in advance for the help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Find_text As String
Dim Replace_text As String
Dim Find_lines As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim Replace_Lines As Variant
Dim y As Integer
Dim find As String
Dim Replace2 As String


Find_text = Find1.Text
Replace_text = Replace1.Text



Find_lines = Split(FindReplace2.Find1, vbCrLf)
Replace_Lines = Split(FindReplace2.Replace1, vbCrLf)
For x = LBound(Find_lines) To UBound(Find_lines)
    find = Find_lines(x)


    For y = LBound(Replace_Lines) To UBound(Replace_Lines)
    Replace2 = Replace_Lines(y)

    Next y
Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: kind of related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118986/search-for-cell-containing-combination-of-words

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems like you only need one loop. Use the same index into your Find and Replace arrays, so you replace all ReplaceLines(1) with FindLines(1). You can record a macro to get the Find/Replace syntax.

Comment: By index do you mean, for example, replace y with x?