# Regex for finding words with no or only one word between them

Tags: regex

I need to find into multiple strings two words with no words or only one word between them. I created the regex for the case to find if those two words exist in string:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b)(?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b)[\s\S]+
```

and it works correctly. 
Then I tried to insert in this regex additional code:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b)(\b\w+\b){0,1}(?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b)[\s\S]+
```

but it didn't work. It selects text with two or more words between searched words. It is not what I need.
First Second - must be selected
First word1 Second - must be selected
First word1 word2 Second - must be not selected by regex, but my regex select it.

Can I get advise how to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps, [`^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b)[\s\S]+`](https://regex101.com/r/V83obS/1)? Or do you also need to match `Second First` and `Second word First`?

Comment: Also, check `^(?=[\s\S]*\b(First|Second)(?:\W+\w+)?\W+(?!\1\b)(?:First|Second)\b)[\s\S]+`

Comment: Yes, I need "Second First" and "Second word First" be  selected. Both of your examples work correctly. Thank you.

Comment: If your requirements are not as shown in the question, please update the question and add sample texts that should match and those that should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause**

You should bear in mind that lookarounds match strings without moving along the string, they ["stand their ground"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground). Once you write `^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b)(\b\w+\b){0,1}(?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b)`, the execution is as follows:

- `^` - the regex engine checks if the current position is the start of string
- `(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b)` - the positive lookahead requires the presence of any 0+ chars followed with a whole word `First` - note that the regex index is still at the start of the string after the lookahead returns *true* or *false*
- `(\b\w+\b){0,1}` - this subpattern is checked only if the above check was *true* (i.e. there is a whole word `First` somewhere) and matches (consumes, moves the regex index) 1 or 0 occurrences of a whole word (i.e. there must be 1 or more word chars *right at the string start*
- `(?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b)` - another positive lookahead that makes sure there is a whole word `Second` somewhere after the first whole word consumed with `\b\w+\b` - if any. Even if the word `Second` is the first word in the string, this will return true since backtracking will step back the word matched with `(\b\w+\b){0,1}` (see, it is optional), and the `Second` will get asserted, and `[\s\S]+` will grab the whole string (Group 1 will be empty). See [the regex demo with `Second word word2 First` string](https://regex101.com/r/cVLbfj/1).

So, your approach cannot guarantee the order of `First` and `Second` in the string, they are just required to be present but not necessarily in the order you expect.

**Solution**

If you need to check the order of `First` and `Second` in the string, you need to combine all the checks into *one single* lookahead. *The approach might turn out very inefficient with longer strings and multiple alternatives in the lookaround*, consider either unrolling the patterns, or trying mutliple regex patterns (like this pseudo-code `if /\bFirst\b/.finds_match().index < /\bSecond\b/.finds_match().index => Good, go on...`).

If you plan to go on with the regex approach, you may match a string that contains `First....Second` only in this order:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b)[\s\S]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V83obS/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b)` - there must be:

  - `[\s\S]*` - any zero or more chars up to the last
  - `\bFirst` - whole word `First`
  - `(?:\W+\w+)?` - optional sequence (1 or 0 occurrences) of 1+ non-word chars and 1+ word chars
  - `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
  - `Second\b` - `Second` as a whole word
- `[\s\S]+` - any 1 or more characters (empty string won't match).

Comment: Yes, it works, but there are some problems for me. This search is for words in some order - First Second, I do not need to find combinations whic are not in this order. Amount of the words can be more than 2. Can be: First Second Third asn so on. All in the order. So for regex pattern formation I use the loop which can form:

Comment: Does it mean the first `^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b)[\s\S]+` regex works for you? You just need the limiting quantifier adjusted as `^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+){2,}\W+Second\b)[\s\S]+`? The `{2,}` means 2 or  more, it won't match if there are less words between `First` and `Second`.

Comment: Yes, it works, but there are not exactly what I need. This search is for words in some order - First Second. I don't need to find combinations whic are not in this order. Amount of the words can be more than 2. Can be: First Second Third and so on. So for regex pattern formation I use  loop which can form -  ^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b)(?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b)[\s\S]+ and pattern with more words. I need snippet of regex expression which estimate only one word and I can insert between (?=[\s\S]*\bFirst\b) and (?=[\s\S]*\bSecond\b) and between other words search if they will be included. Is it possible?

Comment: I will update the answer, but meanwhile, if you want a complete solution, please post the code you use to build the dynamic pattern.

Comment: Between words which I search must be no or only one word.

Comment: I use the code from 1 answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118986/search-for-cell-containing-combination-of-words

Comment: Function FindMultWords(sSearchString As String, aWordList() As String) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim S As String
    Const sP1 As String = "(?=[\s\S]*\b"
    Const sP2 As String = "\b)"
    Const sP3 As String = "[\s\S]+"

    Dim I As Long
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .ignorecase = True
    
        S = "^"
        For I = LBound(aWordList) To UBound(aWordList)
            S = S & sP1 & aWordList(I) & sP2
        Next I
        S = S & sP3
     ....

Comment: Please add all the details to the question, it is hard to read/copy/paste the code in comments. From what I see, it is VBA, please tag the question with the language.

Comment: ^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Third\b)[\s\S]+ this is OK for me. I'll be able to use it in the loop.

Comment: That one will require `First....Second...Third` in the input string. `Second....First...Third` strings will be rejected. Ok, I will adjust the regex solution in the answer.

Comment: I did upvoting.

Comment: I accepted the answer and deleted my own. Wiktor is everything OK now?

Comment: You actually unaccepted the answer. Is there any issue with `^(?=[\s\S]*\bFirst(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Second\b(?:\W+\w+)?\W+Third\‌​b)[\s\S]+`?

Comment: I corrected order and repeated acception. Is it OK now?